# using INotifyPropertyChanged how to Click wpf button

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

i need to update wpf listview when date change. i have already written method which update the listview when click on a button. using INotifyPropertyChanged to trigger the same button on date change. i have below code but need help to click the same button or any other method.

this is the wpf button need to click.
`<Button x:Name="SearchButton" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="344,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="SearchButton_Click" 
FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" />`

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = clock;
        clock.InitClock(); //using another INotifyPropertyChanged to update clock on textbox
        cDate.dateInitClock();
}

public class ChangeDate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DispatcherTimer dateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public string _date { get; set; }
    public string Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string date)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(date));
        }
    }

    public void dateInitClock()
    {
        dateTimer.Tick += dateTimer_Tick;
        dateTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0);
        dateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dateTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        // do we need to add action here?
    }

}
```

Comment: you do not Click (event) you execute a command (`Command={Binding YourCommand`)

Comment: can you help what command i need to add in button.

Comment: done, see the answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Last Edit: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19Zs9Pl-xhpbfcmAATrX_DqM2fk3pXzVE) a link to a working solution for update a column in a `ListView` 
(timer adding 1 min each second)

---

First create a class to your relaycommand

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            //For Vs 2015+ 
            return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
            //For Vs 2013-
            return _canExecute != null ? _canExecute.Invoke(parameter) : true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Can execute changed event handler.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```

then you can execute your command directly from your `ViewModel`

```
//with some validation to enable/disable button click

public virtual ICommand SearchCommand => new RelayCommand(o=> Search(), o=> Validation());

//without validation

 public virtual ICommand SearchCommand => new RelayCommand(o=> Search());

private void Search()
{

}

private bool Validation()
{

}

//using parametres
public virtual ICommand SearchCommand => new RelayCommand(Search);
private void Search(object parameter)
{

}
```

Your XAML

```
<Button Content="Search"  Command={Binding SearchCommand}  />
```

Example of `ListView` binding using MVVM

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourData}">
    <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" 
                  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" >
             </GridViewColumn>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                  Header="Name" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" 
                  Header="Price" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}" 
                  Header="Author" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Catalog}" 
                  Header="Catalog" Width="100"/>
             <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <Button Content="Search"  Command={Binding SearchCommand}  CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>

           </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Your ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyData 
    {
        get { return _myData }
        set
        {
             _myData = value;
             OnPropertiChange(nameof(MyData));
        }
    }

    public virtual ICommand SearchCommand => new RelayCommand(o=> Search());

    private void Search()
    {
        //DoSamething

        MyData = new ObservableCollection<MyData>(ListOfMyData);
    }

}
```

Comment: getting error for CommandManager does not exist in current context also for SearchCommand  a name space cannot directly contains member such as field

Comment: `return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;` maybe?  it needs VS 2015+, I'll update answer

Comment: Take a look at how to use mvvm in wpf, have many examples on the internet, search in google or right here on stackoverflow

Comment: Did you added the references `using System;`
`using System.Diagnostics;`
`using System.Windows.Input;`   in the RelayCommand  class ?

Comment: and most importantly, if you are not using MVVM in your project it is useless to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and not least, as I wrote in the answer, you will use the command in your ViewModel and not in the code behind

Comment: i am not using MVVM it is very basic and simple application. i am already using similar `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update the time on wpf. can this 
 solution be simple.

Comment: anwser udated, [this can help you](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-mvvm/) I've never seen, or read anything that is valid about INotifyPropertyChanged and not using MVVM

Comment: do we have any other method instead of `INotifyPropertyChanged` which call the method Search() when date change without freezing the program/UI. the Search() method do all the calculation and data collection and update it to the wpf UI controls. i cann't use Threading here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160339/discussion-between-celso-livero-and-farhan).

Comment: i have added my solution on chat can you check once.