# How to create and modify a list of selected items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to create an app, where, the right side is a navigatable treeview for directories and a corresponding listview for the files. The files are arranged like icons with templating and styling, and I have it where I can properly select multiple files. The struggle now is putting those selected files into a list/collection that can be added to ANOTHER listview to perform certain actions on it.
Here is the ListView in the MainWindow.xaml:

```
            <ListView x:Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="listview_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel >
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Files}">
                        <DockPanel Width="75" Height="75" >
                                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                            <Image Width="32" Height="32">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/file.png" />
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                            <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Move"/>
                                    <Separator />
                                    <MenuItem Header="Test2" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And the corresponding code under MainWindow.xaml.cs(WIP):

```
        public Files SelectedFile { get; set; }

        public EncryptedFiles SelectedFileEncrypted { get; set; }
        private ObservableCollection<Files> SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<Files>();


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var files = sender;
            var files2 = SelectedItems.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
            //SelectedFile.Encrypt = true;
            //var selectedList = files.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
            foreach (Files file in files2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(file.ToString());

            }

            // MessageBox.Show("2"+files.ToString());
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseRightButtonDown(e);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(e.AddedItems.Count.ToString());
          //  MessageBox.Show(e.RemovedItems.Count.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(e.AddedItems.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(e.RemovedItems.ToString());

            Files files = (Files)listview.SelectedItem;
            if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                //foreach (var file in files)
               // {
                    //Files test = file as Files;
                    SelectedItems.Add(files);
              //  }
            }
            if (e.RemovedItems.Count == 1)
            {
             //   foreach (var file in files)
           //     {
                    //Files test = file as Files;
                    SelectedItems.Remove(files);
            //    }

            }
            for(int i = 0; i < SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(SelectedItems.ElementAt(i).Name);
            }

        }
```

As you can see, I want to be able to transfer certain files from the user directory to a new directory. One way is by selecting them via left-click, and clicking a button that would move them. I also want to be able to right-click and do this but that is another story.

Comment: What is the struggle? Are you getting any errors? If you want to make changes to the same object from two different lists, you need a reference to the same object in the lists.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to get the left column to show the selected files AFTER I click encrypt.

Comment: I see you have an `ObservableCollection`. You might be missing an `OnPropertyChanged` call.

Comment: this example might help you [using INotifyPropertyChanged how to Click wpf button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607012/using-inotifypropertychanged-how-to-click-wpf-button)